# Select site icons in app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I would like to be able to remove site icons from the tool bar. I have six preselected icons of which I use two or three. I would for example like to remove the Outdoors site below

[image: tool bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can already edit the list of pinned sites.

After opening the sidebar with the hamburger at the top left (1), hit the “edit” button (2) above the list of sites:

[image]

That’ll take you to a screen where you can edit the list of sites (you can add, remove and rearrange the sites):

[image]

The list also syncs with the list of communities in the site switcher dropdown on the main site so you can edit it there too:

[image]